# use $http.get in a service/factory to return a collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I try to use a `http.get` promise in an angularjs service, do some manipulation on the obtained collection and finally return it to a controller...

My question is how to use a `$http.get()` in a service in order to obtain and manipulate the result **before** returning it to the controller, like in the code bellow :
[The PEN code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjxQmj?editors=101)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope','customer',function($scope, customer) {
  $scope.odds = customer.odds;
}]);

app.factory('customer', ['$http', function($http) {
  var all = [{'Id':88, 'Name':"A"}, {'Id':89, 'Name':"ShoutNotBeHere"}]; 
  var odds = [];

  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function(response) {
      all = response.records;
    });

  angular.forEach(all, function(c, i) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      odds.push(c);
    }
  });

  return {odds: odds};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    Odd ids from www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="c in odds">
        {{ c.Id + ', ' + c.Name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your forEach and return are outside of your promise, so they won't nessesarily be working with your response data. You have to trigger the foreach and return from inside the `.then` callback

Comment: I understand, but I need to return something in the service...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you could modified the data inside the ajax success call & then return that data from the success. But for returning data from ajax success you need to use promise pattern to return out data from `$http.get`. you need to return the object from the `$http.get` promise, & inside `.then` function of `$http.get` you could manipulate data.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('customer', ['$http', function($http) {
    var all, odds = [];
    var getData = function() {
        return $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
        .then(function(response) {
          all = response.records;
          angular.forEach(all, function(c, i) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
              odds.push(c);
            }
          });
          return odds
        });
    }
    return {
        getData: getData 
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope','customer',function($scope, customer) {
    customer.getData().then(function(response){
         $scope.odds = response;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: @downvoter please do comment to improve other answers OR just tell what you felt wrong?

Comment: no idea why someone could downvote, I upvoted it, now try to understand.. ) thanks for answering

Comment: and is there a way to use in some way a callback function?

Comment: @Serge callback function is not a good practice to implement while you have `promise` like thing here

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty to modify your code to return a promise from the factory, so you can set the value as soon as the promise is resolved.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope','customer',function($scope, customer) {
  customer.then(function(data){
    $scope.odds = data.odds;
    customer.then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}]);

app.factory('customer', ['$http', function($http) {
  var all = [{'Id':88, 'Name':"A"}, {'Id':89, 'Name':"ShoutNotBeHere"}]; 
  var odds = [];
  return $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function(response) {
      all = response.data.records;
      angular.forEach(all, function(c, i) {
      if (i % 2 == 1) {
        c.Id = i;
        odds.push(c);
      }
    });
    return {odds: odds};
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    Odd ids from www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="c in odds">
        {{ c.Id + ', ' + c.Name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that works like a charm... so the only way to return a result in a service with get is to return a promise?!

Comment: Your particular service uses an async operation `$http.get` so the result of the operation is not immediately available to be returned. 
This has nothing to do with how a service should be coded but rather with async operations.
You can return immediate values from services just fine.

Comment: mojet is possible to use a callback function?

Comment: Sorry, I have not read your comment through and answered not to the point.
Yes, you need to return a promise from a service using an async operation because you don't have a result handy at time of return. Also you cannot easily turn an async operation to synchronious, so the solution is either returning a promise or passing callback function to the service call which is logically the same.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation! as Pankaj Parkar was the first to respond I'll consider his answer, but your both solutions are OK ;)